# How to install node.js module in my eclipse kepler in ubuntu

Tags: node.js, eclipse-kepler

I want to install node.js module in my eclipse kepler. For that i search out lot and i find out Enide-Studio-2014-011-20140303-linux-gtk3-x86_64 but i don't want to install new eclipse for node.js i just want to integrate node.js plugin in my existing eclipse kepler .Please help me to overcome this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try nodeclipse. It is based on Eclipse Kepler.

[Nodeclipse](http://www.nodeclipse.org/nts)

Comment: ya i know but i already had eclipse kepler installed so.Is there any way to add node.js plug-in externally in my eclipse kepler

Comment: It's available in the Kepler's marketplace. Just download and install it.